# Hypercohomology spectral sequence from the derived category point of view

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, spectral-sequences

Let $F\colon \mathsf{A}\to\mathsf{B}$ be an additive functor between abelian categories and let $M$ be a complex on $\mathsf{A}$. There's a "hypercohomology spectral sequence"
$$E_1^{i,j}=\mathsf{R}^j F(M^i)\implies \mathsf{R}^{i+j}F(M),$$
which can be constructed, for example, from the spectral sequence of a filtered complex.

Usually the point of view of derived categories clarifies hypercohomology a lot. Can we understand this spectral sequence from this point of view as well? For example, can compute the morphisms in the $E_2$ (or higher pages) using this machinery? Can we obtain the five-term exact sequence from it?

Comment: Given a functor $G: D(A) \to D(B)$ that commutes with filtered colimits and any filtration $X_{\ge *}$ of an object $X$ in $D(A)$, we can try to compute $G(X)$ from $G(X_{\ge *})$. If we choose $G=RF$ and the canonical t-structure filtration of $X$, we get a variant of your sseq above where you replace $M^i$ with the cohomology $H^i(X)$. If we instead had presented $X$ via a cochain complex $M^*$, this produces (and is essentially equivalent) to a filtration on $X$ with associated graded pieces $M^i$, and that filtration gives the sseq in your question.

Comment: @DylanWilson It's possible that I didn't quite understand what you meant, but isn't what you're saying the same as my "[...] which can be constructed from the spectral sequence of a filtered complex"?

My question is more about trying to get more explicit (or at least different) characterizations of the morphisms in this spectral sequence by using derived categories.

Comment: There is a discussion in section 4 of Chapter III in Verdier's thesis: http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1996__239__R1_0/

Comment: Dear @D.-C.Cisinski, thank you for the reference! I’ll take a close look at it. If you could write a quick answer explaining how Verdier’s work solves the problems described above, I would happily award you the bounty :)